# Seaborn: add counts to countplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a way to add the actual count number to the Seaborn's `countplot`? Something similar to `annot=True` in its `heatmap`? I've been looking for it in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), but it seems as it doesn't support it..